# Magento shows blank/empty page

Tags: magento-1.9, error

My site is died after I installed an extension. It show empty page.
I disabled magento compiler as suggest by google. by comment out

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

this 2 lines in includes/config.php. and removed extension manually. the problem still exist.

Then I enabled php error display by adding

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

in index.php. the error show

> Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 93 Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 93 Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'Mage/Core/Model/App.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/app/code/local:/home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/app/code/community:/home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/app/code/core:/home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in
>   /home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 93 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in
>   /home/chorchan/domains/chorchanghatyai.com/public_html/app/Mage.php on
>   line 670

Please help
Thanks

Comment: make sure `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` exists

Comment: OMG the issue was solved. It is my stupid mistake. A million thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento tells that, it can't find the class `Mage_Core_Model_App`. So make sure you have `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` in your application.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is due to *file permissions*:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

and *clear the cache*

```
rm -rf var/cache
```

Comment: the problem still exist